# To show that a certain subset is open in a topological group

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $G$ be a topological group. If $H$ is normal in $G$ then $G/H$ is also a topological group under quotient topology. Let $$\nu:G\rightarrow G/H$$be the natural projection. Further, if $H$ is closed in $G$, then for $[g']\in G/H$, $\{[g']\}$ is a closed subset of $G/H$. Assume $g'\notin H$.  The compliment of $\{[g']\}$ in $G/H$ denoted by $\mathscr{C}\{[g']\}$ is open and $\nu^{-1}\mathscr{C}\{[g']\}$ is open in $G$. One has $$\nu^{-1}\mathscr{C}\{[g']\}=\{g\in G|g\notin[g']\}.$$Let $S$ be a set consisting of one representative from each coset of $H$ except for from $[g']$, the representative of $H$ itself be chosen as the identity element $e$. Then $$\nu^{-1}\mathscr{C}\{[g']\}=\bigcup_{h\in H}h S$$ is another way to express $\nu^{-1}\mathscr{C}\{[g']\}$. If it is further assumed that $H$ is discrete, is it true that $S$ is an open neighbourhood of identity in $G$. If it is, how can this be shown.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Consider $G=\Bbb R$, $H=\Bbb Z$. We can take $S=([0,1)\cap \Bbb Q)\cup ([1,2)\setminus\Bbb Q)$ as very un-open set of representatives.